# PyGame error when trying to load an MP3

Tags: python, audio, youtube, pygame, mp3

My error is:

```
    pygame.mixer.music.load("ytdl.mp3")
pygame.error: Error reading the stream. (code 18)
```

I want to know what this means and how do I solve. I only get this error when I try to download a song using [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) (but i'm sure there are some others which may cause this) and then try to load the file with `pygame.mixer.music.load("ytdl.mp3")`.

If I just load the file from an mp3 file normally, it works fine.

If you need the code for my youtube-dl:

```
    options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'extractaudio': True,
    'audioformat': "mp3",
    'outtmpl': 'ytdl.mp3',
    'noplaylist': True,
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + url])
```

Comment: maybe it downloads corrupted file or YT sends HTML with message that it doesn't like bots and scripts :)

Comment: I forgot to add to the question that it opens fine in any other audio player (Groove or something... windows 10)

Comment: It uses `pygame` and in [PyGame's documentation](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) you can see "Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program"

Answer (score 3):

In pygame MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program.
Pygame is compatible with `.ogg` , `.mid` and mostly `.wav` format.
Best option is to convert your audio file to `.wav` format by using any editing software or online converter and then load it.

```
pygame.mixer.music.load("ytdl.wav")
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.